# Kafka console producer not allowing to write message

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to write some message on topic, but console is not allowing me(producer not waiting for stdin input). I cant see any error log too. Topic is created successfully though. 
I am using :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test.
```

Zookeeper and kafka server are running fine. I am using Mac. What could be the possible issue.
I am following Apache Kafka documentation http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart.

Comment: which version of kafka are you using ? Also, try doing a sudo jps on your terminal and lets know what you see.

Comment: Kafka Version is 0.10.0.0 with 2.11 scala version (kafka_2.11-0.10.0.0) .   Sudo jps results nothing except jps itself.

Answer (score 5):

Ops! the same issue happen to my windows 10, kafka-console-producer.bat file is empty,now i m going to download fresh one to replace existing file.

it works after replacing bat file.

Answer (score 3):

`kafka-console-producer.sh` file is empty. I faced the same issue. The solution is to replace `kafka-console-producer.sh` with a fresh one. This might be an issue that happens only on **Mac OS.**

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to have kafka running as yet.

sudo jps should return something like this :

```
10306 SupportedKafka
17788 Jps
```

saying kafka is running. Check your

```
log.dirs
```

config path (server.properties) to see if there is an exception being thrown during kafka start. Also, Kafka recommends use of the latest Java (1.8) : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#java

Comment: Jps command shows: `14049 Kafka`. Kafka server is running thus.  I am not sure what sudo jps does instead. I was able to produce and consume message using Java classes. Only the problem is with console. Logs do not have any error too. Java version is 1.8 as well.

Comment: jps is a jvm process status tool (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) . I dont know if the .sh is causing a problem in your case. When I run the command as bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test3, it fails for me too. Try without the .sh (bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list localghost:9092 --topic test3)

Comment: It sends error   `-bash: bin/kafka-console-producer: No such file or directory`

Comment: Issue is resolved , I just noticed that kafka-console-producer.sh file is empty . I got new copy of kafka and copied the contents of file. I appreciate your help @sharath.

Comment: Cool ! Its always good practice to compare md5 hashes on software downloads :)

Comment: Wondering how file gets empty!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happened to me too because the file is empty, so i copy pasted the consumer.bat file info into producer.bat and rename the ConsoleConsumer with ConsoleProducer and it worked.

---

@echo off
rem Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
rem this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
rem The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
rem (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
rem the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem limitations under the License.

SetLocal
set KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xmx512M
"%~dp0kafka-run-class.bat" kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer %*
EndLocal